# Keeping passphrase away from telepathic interception

Tags: discussion

I asked a [question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/130828/keeping-passphrase-away-from-telepathic-interception), yes a legitimate question, regarding computer security in face of telepathic interception. Some people are quite  offensive and silly in their responses.

Please provide some suggestions how to make clear to people that asking such questions is legitimate.

I would also appreciate some moderation, saying "this is a tinfoil hat / fantasy pixie dust / imaginary world building" is not the quality of thought that I used to expect from StackExchange community.

Comment: Why is it legitimate? You haven't explained that part yet.

Comment: I do not why I have to even explain this. There is literally nothing in scientific methodology that allows you to say "this is too silly to ask". Science demands, by definition, honest and open inquiry. You cannot close a discussion on grounds "its too silly". That is a violation of scientific principles. Call it a though experiment. You can see some people replied quite seriously. Not everyone sees this as troll question. Btw, there is a lot of answers about flat earth even tho most people do believe its round. Can you explain to me why asking about flat earth is a legitimate question?

Comment: This site is not about scientific principles. This site is not about thought experiments. If you want those, please go elsewhere. From the help page: "Information Security Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for information security professionals"

Comment: Asking about flat earth is also off topic here.

Comment: If it's any consolation, I think your question is at least as valid as the numerous questions about post-quantum cryptography.

Comment: Google this to gain more insight: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22reading+my+thoughts%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: First I found out the earth is flat, and now there are telepathic password crackers targeting us. Today is not a good day for me. If you'll excuse me, I need to equip a tinfoil hat, and recommend that you do the same.

Comment: You should consider gluing tinfoil to the walls instead. Encloses better than a hat. And probably works against wireless bugs too.

Answer (score 5):

On a more general basis, questions regarding theoretical threats are usually closed as off-topic here because one could imagine an infinite number of theoretical threats with as much questions whose answers will be of no practical use for anybody (trust me some people may be *very* creative when they convinced themselves they are being spied upon).

That's why you will not find a study on this site about [the best shape for tinfoil hats](http://www.theatlantic.com/health/archive/2012/09/tin-foil-hats-actually-make-it-easier-for-the-government-to-track-your-thoughts/262998/) ;).

On this site we try to focus on current, documented knowledge. This does not prevent things which first appear to be sci-fi to become actual facts, but they become so after a proper demonstration or irrefutable proof that the technique is *practically* usable (even a lot of things which are true in lab conditions become unusable in real life scenarios).

Meanwhile, most theoretical issues can be boiled down to some already known (and often already addressed) issues. For instance, in the current case as suggested by other members your question falls into ensuring that some user cannot determine just by himself the right password to connect a service, with OTP being the most standard way to address this.

Answer (score 4):

It is not on topic here. Sorry.

Please read the site scope.

Just because you think this is a legitimate question here does not make it so.

Asking a silly question will elicit silly responses. And currently telepathy is a silly topic to ask here.

I was close to closing it as a trolling question - the comments you got were relatively polite.

Comment: Please direct me to site scope page.

Comment: Start with the [about] page, but all of the information you need is under the help link at the top.

Comment: Sorry, I simply do not see it. Please provide a direct quote. And no, the comments were not relatively polite. Please see my comment above.

Comment: See my comment above.